# Xamarin Android new files are not tracked by git

Tags: c#, git, xamarin, xamarin.android, repository

I have a Xamarin.Android project. Whenever I create a new .cs file in the project the file is not tracked by git. I can't see any new changes in my git client - Sourcetree - that I have created/added a new file. This issue is only on my Xamarin.Android project not my Xamarin.iOS project. I'm developing on a Mac computer.

These file which is not tracked by git has this white circle with a cross icon next to them.

[image]
    [image]

Comment: Please check the .gitignore file, maybe the folder of these files have been igonred. You can also use git command to add them, `git status`, `git add .`,`git commit`， `git push`.

Comment: @JoeLv You was right the folders have been ignored, but how can I unignore these folder? So far I have done what you have told with git add and that works, but the files are stil ignored. It seems like my whole Xamarin.Android is ignored, but I can see that it should be in my .gitnore file. I have update my Q with my .gitnore file.

Answer (score 0):

> but I can see that it should be in my .gitnore file

Please check the [.gitignore file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), if the Xamarin.Android folder is within that, it will be untracked to ignore, you need to remove your Xamarin.Android folder from the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that i can't see that Xamarin.Android folder is declared in my .gitignore file.

Comment: Try remove .git file in your project, and `git init` on your project and `git add` which you want to track.

Comment: You can use `git status` to check which file not be tracked, and then use `git add filename` to track. So the local git will manage your code, and then you can use `git push` to push your code to github.